# Special characters from FCM server for regional languages in android Ex: Telugu

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending Telugu word హలో to FCM server by subscribing to below topic.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

Some integers are coming back from FCM in place of హలో in the method onMessageReceived.

I need హలో from FCM server. How to get rid from this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding and Decoding works

While sending to FCM server

```
// Sending to FCM
byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

While receiving

```
// Receiving from FCM onMessageReceived
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

It works pretty well.